# Distribute incremented probabilities for a column that sum to one

Tags: r

Say I have the `values <- c(1:30)` and for each value I want to assign a probability. The probabilities assigned should be in order from the least to the largest, equally spaced and not start on zero.

My first thought was something like this

```
values <- c(1:30)

probabilities <- rep(0, length(values))

for (i in values) {
  probabilities[i + 1] <- probabilities[i] + 1 / length(values)
}
```

But the sum does not equal to one here. Example:

Values: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`

Probab: `0.0417, 0.0917, 0.1417, 0.1917, 0.2417, 0.2917`

Comment: What statistical distribution should be the basis? Without this information, it's completely arbitrary what number I assign, i.e. I could just start with 0.001, then 0.002, then 0.003 and then whatever is the gap to 1 I would assign to your 30th value.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `values` and corresponding `probabilities` ? Maybe reduce `values` to `values <- 1:8` so that it is easier to provide the output.

Comment: They should just be equally spaced, in increasing ordered and increase with one single increment. So the values of the probabilities depends on the length of my values array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
values <- 1:30
probabilities_raw <- values/(length(values)+1)
probabilities_rescaled <- probabilities_raw/sum(probabilities_raw)
sum(probabilities_rescaled)
```

The raw probs in this case are:

```
probabilities_raw
 [1] 0.03225806 0.06451613 0.09677419 0.12903226 0.16129032 0.19354839 0.22580645
 [8] 0.25806452 0.29032258 0.32258065 0.35483871 0.38709677 0.41935484 0.45161290
[15] 0.48387097 0.51612903 0.54838710 0.58064516 0.61290323 0.64516129 0.67741935
[22] 0.70967742 0.74193548 0.77419355 0.80645161 0.83870968 0.87096774 0.90322581
[29] 0.93548387 0.96774194
```

And the rescaled ones:

```
probabilities_rescaled
 [1] 0.002150538 0.004301075 0.006451613 0.008602151 0.010752688 0.012903226 0.015053763
 [8] 0.017204301 0.019354839 0.021505376 0.023655914 0.025806452 0.027956989 0.030107527
[15] 0.032258065 0.034408602 0.036559140 0.038709677 0.040860215 0.043010753 0.045161290
[22] 0.047311828 0.049462366 0.051612903 0.053763441 0.055913978 0.058064516 0.060215054
[29] 0.062365591 0.064516129
```

And the rescaled ones sum up to 1.

Comment: Great, this was exactly what I was looking for. I also edited my question to provide an example of what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Note, though, that in your example you have 8 input values, but will get 6 probabilities, whereas in my case you get as many probabilities as you have input values.